# change value of variable outside function

Tags: python, function

I want to increment `p` with the help of function and use it in another function, e.g.

```py
p = 0
def o():
    global p
    p += 1
    print(p)
    return(p)
```

In this code I want to use the value of `p` after running the function multiple times.

The output from "`print()`" and "`return`" in the function are as expected but I need the value of `p` to change too. How can I change the value of `p` too?
I have tried to use another variable to get the value of `p` to but it didn't work.

Comment: You _almost certainly_ don't want to do this. `global` is roughly translated to "disaster" from python.

Comment: I agree that using `global` is probably not a good idea.  You certainly don't need to use a global *and* return a value.  But I am stumped what your problem actually is.  I entered your exact function, called it multiple times, and the value of `p` changed as expected.

Comment: Can you explain better what's your problem? What are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

```
p = 0
def o():
    global p
    p += 1
print(p) # -> 0
o()
print(p) # -> 1
```

But I would recommend putting the p variable inside the (), that would make the code way cleaner and you can prevent more errors and bugs in bigger and more complex systems.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Having a function manipulate a global value like you implemented is usually not the way to go. Since this function could be called by you or a collaborating programmer from everywhere this could alter a variable you depend on in a different area of your script. Furthermore you might want to be able to use the same function to increment different variables.

Therefore a solution like this would be preferable:

```
def increment(value_to_increment):
    value_to_increment += 1
    return value_to_increment

p= 0
p = increment(p)
print(p)
```